# How to use CUSTOM privacy setting for facebook post from an app in php

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In PHP with facebook SDK, when I post from my app using /me/feed, if I use 'SELF' for privacy setting, it works fine.  When I change it to CUSTOM with a list of ids to restrict to, I get an error for "friends" was not recognized.  What does this mean?

// Works

```
$privacy = array(
   'value' => 'SELF',
);
```

// Doesn't work and says 'Friends was not recognized'

```
$privacy = array(
    'value' => 'CUSTOM',
    'allow' => '{<id1>}'
}
```

I read through many questions on this topic before asking this one.

Also, this documentation from FB is confusing me as to what is and is not possible for an post from an app.

"Note: The privacy parameter only applies for posts to the user's own timeline and is ultimately governed by the privacy ceiling a user has configured for an app. It does not apply to posts made by an app on behalf of a user to another user's timelines or to Pages, events, or groups. In those cases, such posts are viewable by anyone who can see the timeline or content in the group or event."

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a parameter called 'friends' with the value of 'SOME_FRIENDS'.

like this:

```
$privacy = array(
    'value' => 'CUSTOM',
    'friends' => 'SOME_FRIENDS',
    'allow' => 'id1,id2,id3'
);
```